# Unlimited Upvoting Comments

Tags: support, comments, up-votes

When I use my max amount of votes per day, I still can upvote comments. Whys that? I can vote as many of comments as I want

Comment: At a guess, because upvotes on comments do not confer reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate limit of 30 per day, listed over on Meta SE:

[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)